# Galleriffic and multiple galleries on wordpress page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, gallery

I think I'm close to figuring this out and would like some help to get this working properly. I am using dynamically generated IDs from Wordpress Post ID numbers to create unique Galleriffic galleries. My script seems to be grabbing only one unique selector and not any other.

You can see the page [here](http://74.208.171.75/clients/aspca/)

Here is the galleriffic init code:

```
var galleryId = $('.gallery').attr('id');
var slideId = $('#'+galleryId+' > div');
var currentId = $('.thumbs_group').attr('id');
$('#'+galleryId).galleriffic('#'+currentId, {
    imageContainerSel: slideId
});
```

Again, this code is only affecting the first gallery and not the second gallery.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are only applying the function to one galleryID, try

**Updated code:** replace all your code above with this:

```
$('.gallery').each(function(){
   $(this).galleriffic($(this).next(), {
       imageContainerSel: $(this).find('.slideshow')
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but that didn't seem to work. I updated my script using your suggestion and I am now calling two different galleries but the images are being placed into both image containers. I think I need to call a unique container somehow.

Comment: what do you mean being placed into both image containers?

Comment: I've been modified the script again, but you can view it again at the link above. Each gallery contains an image container and I can't seem to get each gallery to display images within its own image container. How can I select a unique image container within each gallery?

Comment: after inspecting your page, I think you are going around with the code. more direct code would be above. try that first. and see how it comes out.

Comment: Awesome, that worked great. Just what I needed. Though I've noticed that I can't use the Galleriffic advanced settings with this code. The default advanced init code looks like this: 

var gallery = $('#thumbs').galleriffic({ ... });

without the each function.